# How do I know which STL string implementation I'm using?

Tags: c++, string, stl

Item 15 of Effective STL says that there are at least 6 different implementations of std::string. But if I have to be aware of which implementation I'm using, how do I find out which implementation I'm using?
std::string of gcc does not show the source code (it's all in the .so file), so how do I find out?
Couldn't find anything [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/), so if in future I need to look up such info, where could I search?

Comment: Why does it matter?  As long as the implementation meets the standard requirements, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the `<string>` header and watch the copyright? I'll add that, from what I know, `std::string` is a typedef of `basic_string<>`, so of a template class. Now, from what I remember, only Comeau C++ supports "export" templates, so all other compilers need to have template classes defined AND implemented in header files. You are using GCC so probably in the `<string>` header you'll find a big piece of the string implementation. (I'll add that it's a common trick to make a template "shim"/"proxy" that calls non-templated classes to minimize the compilation size, so not all the implementation truly needs to be in the header file and that, for the specific case of the `std::string` many methods COULD be defined on top of the C "string" library (but probably won't because `std::string` considers `null` as a valid character)

Comment: Ah! Found it! It was in basic_string.h. Thanks :)

Comment: the reason `basic_string` is a template is so it doesn't need to make assumptions about the type of characters it will handle - C "string" won't support wide characters etc., so at most could only be used by specialisations for `char`, but that would simply make the code more complex and could result in unnecessary out-of-line calls.  (Separately, another trick is to make a non-templated wrapper with an implementation using a specific template instantiation, such that the template header doesn't need to be exposed-to/parsed-by each client).